# Geth not synchronizing - Firewall issue?

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, fast-sync, firewalls

I am trying to sync an ethereum node on my computer, which is connected to a university network.

However it seems that `geth` is not finding any peers, same thing with `mist`. It looks to me like the port used by `geth` to synchronize (30303 from what I understood) the node is blocked.

Is there any way I could use a different port ?

**Update:**

I found a way to change the port, and even enable upnp, from the `geth` command-line [documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options) :

```
--port value          Network listening port (default: 30303)
--nat value           NAT port mapping mechanism (any|none|upnp|pmp|extip:<IP>) (default: "any")
```

However, synchronization still does not start. Here is what I get when running the `geth --fast --cache=4096 --port=10350 --nat=upnp` command :

```
I0320 12:09:23.150087 p2p/server.go:608] Listening on [::]:10350
I0320 12:09:23.152087 node/node.go:341] IPC endpoint opened: \\.\pipe\geth.ipc
```

And it stays stuck here...

Comment: If you're listening on a different port to the rest of the public network, then you're not going to hear anything. You would need to find a way to forward port 30303 for both UDP and TCP. It's possible that your university blocks traffic on all but the most standard ports. (It would be worth asking them.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your university is blocking port 30303. Probably do not want people mining Ethereum on free power.